# PersonPicture doesn't behave as expected when text is in some other languages

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm using [UWP's PersonPicture class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.personpicture) in order to list several items.
When no image is assigned, the avatar circle next to the person's name is expected to show a letter (or two) according to that person's name.

However, when the name contains only non-Latin/Cyrillic characters, it seems to just display the same general image of a user glyph - instead of using the first letter from the assigned name.
See screenshot for example:

[image: example screenshot]

I wonder if there's a workaround to this, or it's just a known issue which hopefully will be fixed in a later version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PersonPicture` does not make name abbreviations for non-Latin languages.

For non-Latin names, developers can write abbreviations and apply them to `PersonPicture`.

### Usage

```xml
<PersonPicture DisplayName="अब्दुल" Initials="अ"/>
```

The `Initials` property could gets or sets the initials of the contact's name. I believe this attribute can meet your requirements.

Best regards.

Comment: That worked, also in code-behind! Should have said that I did try setting `BadgeText` but that didn't help, yet I didn't notice there's also `Initials` until you said. Thanks!